# How to stop google cloud sql from corrupting database tables

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Today I noticed my wordpress website one GAE-php has no more posts and the logs claim

> WordPress database error Table './dbname/wp_posts' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Some time before that I saw errors in log relating to "duplicate keys", but I can't seem to be able to find exact errors now through log viewer.

- Why are this errors occurring on Google Cloud SQL,
- how can I stop them from happening and,
- is there another option to store this data in a way that will not corrupt tables?

Comment: I found the "Duplicate entry" error and it probably stems from this: "WordPress database error Incorrect key file for table './dbname/wp_posts.MYI'; try to repair it for query INSERT INTO `wp_posts`..."

Answer (score 2):

.MYI files indicate to me that you're using MyISAM. Cloud SQL strongly [recommends you use InnoDB](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq). Try changing your tables to use InnoDB instead, which the previous link also describes how to do.